# How to read other process memory

Tags: pointers, delphi-xe2, rtti, readprocessmemory, wm-copydata

So, I have a class that uses WM_COPYDATA to allow applications to communicate.

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    Name: string[255];
    Age: integer;
    Birthday: TDateTime;
  end;

function TAppCommunication.SendRecord(const ARecordToSend: Pointer; const ARecordType: PTypeInfo): Boolean;
var
  _Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  _Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    _Stream.Write(NativeInt(ARecordType), SizeOf(TTypeInfo));
    _Stream.Write(NativeInt(ARecordToSend), SizeOf(ARecordToSend));
    _Stream.Position := 0;

    Result := SendStreamData(_Stream, TCopyDataType.cdtRecord)
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_Stream);
  end;
end;

function TAppCommunication.SendStreamData(const AStream: TMemoryStream;
  const ADataType: TCopyDataType): Boolean;
var
  _CopyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  Result := False;

  if AStream.Size = 0 then
    Exit;

  _CopyDataStruct.dwData := integer(ADataType);
  _CopyDataStruct.cbData := AStream.Size;
  _CopyDataStruct.lpData := AStream.Memory;

  Result := SendData(_CopyDataStruct);
end;

function TAppCommunication.SendData(const ADataToSend: TCopyDataStruct)
  : Boolean;
var
  _SendResponse: integer;
  _ReceiverHandle: THandle;
begin
  Result := False;

  _ReceiverHandle := GetRemoteReceiverHandle;
  if (_ReceiverHandle = 0) then
    Exit;

  _SendResponse := SendMessage(_ReceiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA,
    integer(FLocalReceiverForm.Handle), integer(@ADataToSend));

  Result := _SendResponse <> 0;
end;
```

Sending application:

```
procedure TSenderMainForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _AppCommunication: TAppCommunication;
  _ms: TMemoryStream;
  _Rec: TMyRec;
  _Record: TAttrData;
begin
  _AppCommunication := TAppCommunication.Create('LocalReceiverName', OnAppMessageReceived);
  _ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    _AppCommunication.SetRemoteReceiverName('LocalReceiverNameServer');
    _AppCommunication.SendString('ąčęėįšųūž123');
    _AppCommunication.SendInteger(998);
    _AppCommunication.SendDouble(0.95);

    _Rec.Name := 'Edijs';
    _Rec.Age := 29;
    _Rec.Birthday := EncodeDate(1988, 10, 06);
    _Record.Len := 1988;
    //_ms.Write(_Rec, SizeOf(TMyRec));
    //_AppCommunication.SendStreamData(_ms, TCopyDataType.cdtRecord);
    _AppCommunication.SendRecord(@_rec, System.TypeInfo(TMyRec));
    //_AppCommunication.SendRecord(@_Record, System.TypeInfo(TAttrData));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_ms);
    FreeAndNil(_AppCommunication);
  end;
end;
```

Receiving application:

```
procedure TReceiverMainForm.OnAppMessageReceived(const ASender
  : TPair<HWND, string>; const AReceivedData: TCopyDataStruct;
  var AResult: integer);
var
  Info: PTypeInfo;
  Data: PTypeData;
  KindName: String;
  SubName: String;
  _TypeInfo: TTypeInfo;
  _MyRec: TMyRec;
begin
....
  else
  begin
    memLog.Lines.Add('Unknown data received.');

    if (AReceivedData.dwData) = integer(TCopyDataType.cdtRecord) then
    begin
      memLog.Lines.Add('Record received.');

       // This one works fine if "_Stream.Write(NativeInt(ARecordType), SizeOf(TTypeInfo));"
       // is commented out
      //_MyRec := GetProcessMyRec(ASender.Key, pointer(NativeUint(AReceivedData.lpData^)), SizeOf(TMyRec));

      _TypeInfo := GetProcessTypeInfo(ASender.Key,
        Pointer(AReceivedData.lpData^), SizeOf(TTypeInfo));

      Info := System.TypeInfo(TMyRec);
      if (_TypeInfo.Name = Info^.Name) and (_TypeInfo.Kind = Info^.Kind) then
      begin
        // _MyRec := GetProcessMyRec(ASender.Key, Pointer(AReceivedData.lpData^), SizeOf(TMyRec)); works
        _MyRec := GetProcessMyRec(ASender.Key, pointer(NativeInt(AReceivedData.lpData^) +
          SizeOf(TTypeInfo)), SizeOf(TMyRec));

        ShowMessage(_MyRec.Name + ', Age: ' + IntToStr(_MyRec.Age) + ', birthday: ' +
          DateToStr(_MyRec.Birthday));
      end;
    end;
    AResult := -1;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that if I am sending TypeInfo and the record together, i fail at reading second one. I can read TypInfo or record if I send them separately. What should I fix to make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use pointers across process boundaries, let alone pointers to RTTI. You should not be sending *a pointer* to a `TMyRec` (and certainly not *a pointer* to its RTTI). You need to send a copy of the *actual* `TMyRec` itself (you have code commented out to do exact that), eg:

```
type
  PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
  TMyRec = packed record
    Name: string[255];
    Age: integer;
    Birthday: TDateTime;
  end;
```

```
function TAppCommunication.SendRecord(const ARecordToSend: Pointer; ARecordSize: Integer): Boolean;
var
  _Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  _Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    _Stream.WriteBuffer(ARecordToSend^, ARecordSize);
    _Stream.Position := 0;
    Result := SendStreamData(_Stream, TCopyDataType.cdtRecord);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_Stream);
  end;
end;

...

// need to cast to WPARAM and LPARAM, not Integer...
_SendResponse := SendMessage(_ReceiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, WPARAM(FLocalReceiverForm.Handle), LPARAM(@ADataToSend)); 

... 

var
   _Rec: TMyRec;

_Rec.Name := 'Edijs';
_Rec.Age := 29;
_Rec.Birthday := EncodeDate(1988, 10, 06);
_AppCommunication.SendRecord(@_Rec, SizeOf(_Rec));
```

```
procedure TReceiverMainForm.OnAppMessageReceived(const ASender : TPair<HWND, string>; const AReceivedData: TCopyDataStruct; var AResult: integer);
var
  _MyRec: PMyRec;
begin
  ....
  else
  begin
    if AReceivedData.dwData = Ord(TCopyDataType.cdtRecord) then
    begin
      memLog.Lines.Add('Record received.');
      _MyRec := PMyRec(AReceivedData.lpData);
      // Use _MyRec^ data as needed...
      ShowMessage(_MyRec.Name + ', Age: ' + IntToStr(_MyRec.Age) + ', birthday: ' + DateToStr(_MyRec.Birthday));
    end else
      memLog.Lines.Add('Unknown data received.');
    AResult := -1;
  end;
end;
```

If you need to send multiple types of records under the same `cdtRecord` ID then you need to send the actual record type name (not its RTTI) before the record data, eg:

```
function TAppCommunication.SendRecord(const ARecordType: ShortString; const ARecordToSend: Pointer; ARecordSize: Integer): Boolean;
var
  _Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  _Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    _Stream.WriteBuffer(@ARecordType, 1+Length(ARecordType));
    _Stream.WriteBuffer(ARecordToSend^, ARecordSize);
    _Stream.Position := 0;
    Result := SendStreamData(_Stream, TCopyDataType.cdtRecord);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_Stream);
  end;
end;

var
   _Rec: TMyRec;

_Rec.Name := 'Edijs';
_Rec.Age := 29;
_Rec.Birthday := EncodeDate(1988, 10, 06);
_AppCommunication.SendRecord('TMyRec', @_Rec, SizeOf(_Rec));
```

```
procedure TReceiverMainForm.OnAppMessageReceived(const ASender : TPair<HWND, string>; const AReceivedData: TCopyDataStruct; var AResult: integer);
var
  _RecType: ShortString;
  _RecData: Pointer;
  _MyRec: PMyRec;
begin
  ....
  else
  begin
    if AReceivedData.dwData = Ord(TCopyDataType.cdtRecord) then
    begin
      memLog.Lines.Add('Record received.');
      _RecType := PShortString(AReceivedData.lpData)^;
      _RecData := PByte(AReceivedData.lpData)+1+Length(_RecType);
      if (_RetType = 'TMyRec') then
      begin
        _MyRec := PMyRec(_RecData);
        // Use _MyRec^ data as needed...
        ShowMessage(_MyRec.Name + ', Age: ' + IntToStr(_MyRec.Age) + ', birthday: ' + DateToStr(_MyRec.Birthday));
      end
      else
      ...
    end else
      memLog.Lines.Add('Unknown data received.');
    AResult := -1;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, you need to use a more elaborate serialization mechanism to identify your record types and fields in a more generalized manner.